# How can i select specific columns from excel sheet in c#?

Tags: c#, excel

How can I select specific columns from excel sheet rather than all columns

```
string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", txtPath.Text);
string query = String.Format("select * from [{0}$]", "Sheet1");
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 7):

What about:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B14:C20]
```

This should select cells `B14` to `C20`.

Answer (score 1):

This will sound trivial but this is what I understand from your question. Instead of `SELECT *` use `SELECT [columnName1],[columnName2] FROM  Sheet1.`. Here `columnName1` and `columnName2` should be the headers of columns that you want to get from `Excel Sheet`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the data before populating [here is a good reference](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx) on advanced select statements. If you want to manipulate your data post populating your DataSet then here's how:

```
DataTable myTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

var myColumn = myTable.Columns["ColumnName"];
```

or

```
var myColumn = myTable.Columns[0];
```

To access a single field it would look something like this.

```
var field = myTable.Rows[0][myColumn];
```

Comment: I need to specify the columns before filling the dataset

Comment: @amer I have only done that through the Jet engine when knowing my Column Titles. I provided a link that I hope will help.