# Oledb connection and query read only one column from excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, oledb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i select specific columns from excel sheet in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150684/how-can-i-select-specific-columns-from-excel-sheet-in-c)

```
string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|2.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=no;'";

string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, strConn);

da.Fill(excelDataSet);

GridView1.DataSource = excelDataSet;
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "CheckNumber";
```

I have this code to read an Excel Spreadsheet being loaded from a website and being displayed in a `gridview`.  I would like to simply just read column A on the spreadsheet.  I think I should be able to change this `string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";` but all my efforts have been futile.  Can someone point me in the right direction, or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: This link might have some helpful stuff for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232281/oledb-mixed-excel-datatypes-missing-data/5721521#5721521

Comment: thank you, i have been searching for a while and i couldnt come up with it.

Answer (score 3):

it looks like the way to do this is simply
string sql = "SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5 FROM [sheet1$];
Thanks for the comments everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies in the fact that a spreadsheet is not a database. A spreadsheet is under no obligation to be rectangular or have cells of the same type.  So saying you want a column ASSUMES that that column exists for all rows and is of the same type.  So before you issue SQL against it you need to convert to a vector of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use to read an Excel Spreadsheet and return it as a DataTable and if you focus in on the following section where I am able to query all of the workbooks in the Spreadsheet by looping through the dtSchema DataTable object to find the names of the different worksheets:

```
public static DataTable GetExcelData(string connectionString)
{
    string sql = string.Empty;
    using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (OleDbCommand command = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cn.Open();
                DataTable dtSchema = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dtSchema.Rows)
                    {
                        //Will Loop through the name of each Worksheet
                        Console.WriteLine(dr["Table_Name"]);
                    }


                string firstSheetName = dtSchema.Rows[0].Field<string>("TABLE_NAME");

                sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + firstSheetName + "]";
                command.CommandText = sql;
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    dt.Load(reader);
                }
                cn.Close();
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems like i should be able to learn something from this but i cant really follow what is going on and it really dosent answer the question that i asked wich is how to get just one column from an excel spreadsheet. thanks for the reply though.