# Is pick and choose columns from excel possible in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have to read a 450 column excel file and dump few of the column (150+) information into SQL.

I have splitted the excel into 2 parts and then merging. Is it possible to replace the excel column names in the below named range query .

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Sheet1$A:GR]
```

Expected query:

```
SELECT  F1, F2, F3, F45, F78, .....
FROM    [Sheet1$]

SELECT  colName, colPlace, colAnimal, colThing, .....
FROM    [Sheet1$]
```

I have tried the above 2 options but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify columns names in SQL command while querying an excel file, you have to make sure that:

1. If the Excel connection is configured to read first row as header then you should use a similar approach:

   ```
   SELECT [column name 1], [column name 2] FROM [Sheet1$]
   ```
2. If first row doesn't contain header then you should use `[1], [2], ...`

You can refer to the following articles for more details:

- [Writing SQL Queries against Excel files (Excel SQL)](https://querysurge.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205766136-Writing-SQL-Queries-against-Excel-files-Excel-SQL-)
- [How to select specific columns Excel. Then saved in a database. C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/699624/How-to-select-specific-columns-Excel-Then-saved-in)
- [How can i select specific columns from excel sheet in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150684/how-can-i-select-specific-columns-from-excel-sheet-in-c)
- [Read Write Excel file with OLEDB in C# (without Interop)](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/9014/read-write-excel-file-with-oledb-in-c-without-interop)